# Why do $\Gamma_{ij}^k\delta_{k}^{m}=\Gamma_{ij}^m$

Tags: differential-geometry, index-notation

> $$\Gamma_{ij}^k\delta_{k}^{m}=\Gamma_{ij}^m$$

Isn't it a scalar matrix?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_summation_convention

Comment: Note that the entities that appear in the expression, i.e. $\Gamma_{ij}^k, \delta_{k}^{m}$ and $\Gamma_{ij}^m$, are just real numbers. Some of the indices on the left-hand side indicate that what's there is actually a shorthand for some sum, and the rest of the indices indicate that these are the entries of some table (which some, if so inclined, might call a matrix, although this one is three-dimensional), but the entities themselves are _just numbers_.

Comment: @Arthur so this is an expression of a matrix?

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$\Gamma_{ij}^k\delta_k^m=\sum_{k=1}^n\Gamma_{ij}^k\delta_k^m.$$ Now, $$\delta_k^m=\begin{cases}1, & k=m;\\ 0, &k\ne m.\end{cases}$$ Thus

$$\Gamma_{ij}^k\delta_k^m=\sum_{k=1}^n\Gamma_{ij}^k\delta_k^m=\Gamma_{ij}^m.$$